# How to run a XUL application in Mac OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul, xulrunner, osx-leopard

I am trying to create a XUL "Hello World" application in Mac OS X. I download the XULRunner from [here](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/2.0rc1/runtimes/), followed [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Getting_started_with_XULRunner) and then [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial) and then [this tutorial](http://www.xul.fr/tutorial/)... None worked. So, I looked at it better and found [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Getting_started_with_XULRunner#Mac), whose instructions I followed. Unfortunately, it does not work yet. I even can run the application with the command

```
/Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/xulrunner-bin $PWD/application.ini
```

However, no window is presented and no error is printed. It happens when I try to run the application with `firefox -app` too.

What can be wrong? Also, does someone know some tutorial which would work? It would be an acceptable answer, too :)

Thanks in advance!

## File contents

The content of the `application.ini` file is:

```
[App]
Vendor=Me
Name=Zull
Version=1.0
BuildID=31052011
ID=zull-xul@zull.com

[Gecko]
MinVersion=2.0
MaxVersion=2.*
```

The content of `chrome/chrome.manifest` is:

```
content zull file:content/
```

The content of `chrome/content/main.xul` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window id="main" title="My App" width="300" height="300"
    xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <caption label="Hello World"/>
</window>
```

Finally, the content of `defaults/preferences/prefs.js` is:

```
pref("toolkit.defaultChromeURI", "chrome://zull/content/main.xul");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the recommendations of Wladimir Palant, I changed the content of `chrome/chrome.manifest` from

```
content zull file:content/
```

to

```
content zull content/
```

Then, following [these instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Getting_started_with_XULRunner#Step_5.3a_Set_up_the_chrome_manifest), I created a `chrome.manifest` file in the root app dir whose content is

```
manifest chrome/chrome.manifest
```

It is required because the default place for `chrome.manifest` in XULRunner 2.0 is the root app directory.

However, the error `No chrome package registered for chrome:///User/brandizzi/sandbox/zull/main.xul` persisted. Then, I got it: trying to solve the problem, I experienced using the full path to the `main.xul` file in `defaults/preferences/prefs.js`:

```
pref("toolkit.defaultChromeURI", "chrome:///User/brandizzi/sandbox/zull/main.xul");
```

I just changed it to the chrome path...

```
pref("toolkit.defaultChromeURI", "chrome://zull/content/main.xul");
```

...and it worked.

It was a bunch of silly errors nonetheless but it is solved now. [This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.xul/browse_thread/thread/cf72b8441205ca9f#) was very helpful to me. Also, Wladimir recommendation about using the `-jsconsole` option of XULRunner (such as in `/Library/Frameworks/XUL.framework/xulrunner-bin  ~/sandbox/zull/application.ini -jsconsole`) was very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I can see only one obvious mistake here. The contents of your chrome.manifest file should be:

```
content zull content/
```

Generally, you can always add the `-jsconsole` flag to the command line. This will open the Error Console and will often show you what's wrong.

Comment: I updated `chrome.manifest` and ran xulrunner with `-jsconsole`. The console presented the message `Could not read chrome manifest file .../zull/chrome.manifest`. I copied `chrome.manifest` to the app root dir and then got the message `No chrome package registered for chrome:.../main.xul`. I think it is another problem, so I'll  mark your question as the answer and ask another one because `-jsconsole` is in some way what I was looking for.